# How can I make the month value be a two digit number?

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing this date picker but need the month value to be a two digit number rather than a one-digit number in the form.

https://www.cssscript.com/date-picker-calendar/

I've been looking at the JS code but can't find a line in which the month value is created.

```
// GLOBAL CONSTANTS
const SECOND = 1000;
const MINUTE = SECOND * 60;
const HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
const DAY = HOUR * 24;
const WEEK = DAY * 7;

const weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
const weekdays_short = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const months_short = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];


// PROTOTYPES
Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function () {
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 
this.getDate()));
var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
};

// DATEPICKER
class Datepicker {
constructor(host, s) {
    const t = this;
    t.host = host;
    t.frame = document.createElement("div");
    t.frame.id = "datepicker-frame";
    t.frame.className = "noselect";



    // Run config if settings present
    if (s) t.config(s);

    // Show conditions
    window.onresize = () => { if (t.display_state) show(true); }; 
// to update screen position
     document.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (
            e.target == document.getElementById("id_completed_at") &&
            !document.getElementById("datepicker-frame")
        ) {
            t.load("day"); // Start date when opening
            show(true);
        }
        else if (
            document.getElementById("datepicker-frame") != null &&
            !e.path.includes(document.getElementById("datepicker-frame"))
        ) show(false);
    });

    // Load
    t.load = function (n) {
        while (t.frame.firstChild) t.frame.removeChild(t.frame.firstChild);

        t.head = document.createElement("ul");
        t.frame.append(t.head);

        t.table = document.createElement("table");
        t.frame.append(t.table);
        t.table.className = n;

        // If data is month
        if (n == "day") {
            // Prev
            const prev = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(prev);
            prev.innerHTML = "<<";
            if (t.firstdate == undefined || (
                t.date.getMonth() > t.firstdate.getMonth() ||
                t.date.getFullYear() > t.firstdate.getFullYear())
            ) {
                prev.className = "pointer";
                prev.onclick = () => {
                    t.date = new Date(t.date.getFullYear(), t.date.getMonth() - 1, 1);
                    t.load("day");
                };
            } else prev.className = "disabled";

            // month and year
            const head = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(head);
            head.colSpan = 5;
            head.innerHTML = months[t.date.getMonth()] + " " + t.date.getFullYear();
            head.onclick = () => {
                t.load("month");
            };
            head.className = "pointer";

            // Next
            const next = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(next);
            next.innerHTML = ">>";
            if (t.lastdate == undefined || (
                t.date.getMonth() < t.lastdate.getMonth() ||
                t.date.getFullYear() < t.lastdate.getFullYear())
            ) {
                next.className = "pointer";
                next.onclick = () => {
                    t.date = new Date(t.date.getFullYear(), t.date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
                    t.load("day");
                };
            } else next.className = "disabled";

            // Header row [Weekdays]
            const row = document.createElement("tr");
            t.table.append(row);
            for (let day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
                const cell = document.createElement("th");
                cell.innerHTML = weekdays_short[day];
                row.append(cell);
            }

            // Dates
            const first_day_in_month = new Date(t.date.getFullYear(), t.date.getMonth(), 1);
            let index = 1 - (first_day_in_month.getDay() || 7);
            for (let y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
                const tr = document.createElement("tr");
                t.table.append(tr);
                for (let x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
                    const day = new Date(first_day_in_month.getTime() + DAY * index);

                    const td = document.createElement("td");
                    tr.append(td);
                    td.innerHTML = day.getDate();

                    if (day.getMonth() == t.date.getMonth() && t.disableddays(day) && (
                        t.firstdate == undefined ? true : (
                            day.getMonth() == t.firstdate.getMonth() ? (
                                day.getFullYear() == t.firstdate.getFullYear() ?
                                    day.getDate() >= t.firstdate.getDate() : true
                            ) : true
                        )
                    ) && (
                        t.lastdate == undefined ? true : (
                            day.getMonth() == t.lastdate.getMonth() ? (
                                day.getFullYear() == t.lastdate.getFullYear() ?
                                    day.getDate() <= t.lastdate.getDate() : true
                            ) : true
                        )
                    )) {
                        td.className = "pointer";
                        td.onclick = () => {
                            t.setDate(day);
                            show(false);
                        };
                    } else td.className = "disabled";
                    td.className += day.toDateString() == new Date().toDateString() ? " today" : "";

                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        // If data is year
        else if (n == "month") {
            // Prev
            const prev = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(prev);
            prev.innerHTML = "<<";
            if (t.firstdate == undefined || (
                t.date.getFullYear() > t.firstdate.getFullYear())
            ) {
                prev.className = "pointer";
                prev.onclick = () => {
                    t.date = new Date(t.date.getFullYear() - 1, 1, 1);
                    t.load("month");
                };
            } else prev.className = "disabled";

            // Year
            const head = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(head);
            head.innerHTML = t.date.getFullYear();

            // Next
            const next = document.createElement("li");
            t.head.append(next);
            next.innerHTML = ">>";
            if (t.lastdate == undefined || (
                t.date.getFullYear() < t.lastdate.getFullYear())
            ) {
                next.className = "pointer";
                next.onclick = () => {
                    t.date = new Date(t.date.getFullYear() + 1, 1, 1);
                    t.load("month");
                };
            } else next.className = "disabled";

            // Months
            for (let y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
                const row = document.createElement("tr");
                t.table.append(row);
                for (let x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                    const index = y * 4 + x;
                    const day = new Date(t.date.getFullYear(), index, 1);

                    const cell = document.createElement("td");
                    row.append(cell);
                    cell.innerHTML = months_short[index];

                    if (
                        (t.firstdate != undefined ? day.getTime() >= new Date(t.firstdate).setDate(1) : true) &&
                        (t.lastdate != undefined ? day.getTime() <= new Date(t.lastdate).setDate(1) : true)
                    ) {
                        cell.className = "pointer";
                        cell.onclick = () => {
                            t.date = new Date(t.date.getFullYear(), index, 1);
                            t.load("day");
                        };
                    } else cell.className = "disabled";
                }
            }
        }
    };

    const show = function (bool) {
        if (bool) {
            const rect = t.host.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = (rect.left + rect.right) / 2;
            const y = rect.bottom - rect.top + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            t.frame.style.setProperty("top", y + 20 + "px");
            t.frame.style.setProperty("left", x - 152 + "px");

            document.body.append(t.frame);
        }
        else if (!bool) document.getElementById("datepicker-frame").remove();
    };
}

config(s) {
    this.firstdate = s.firstdate || this.firstdate;
    this.lastdate = s.lastdate || this.lastdate;
    this.disableddays = s.disableddays || this.disableddays || (() => { return true; });
    this.format = s.format || this.format || ((d) => { return d; });

    if (typeof this.firstdate != "object" && this.firstdate != undefined) console.error("firstdate is not of type Object");
    else if (typeof this.lastdate != "object" && this.lastdate != undefined) console.error("lastdate is not of type Object");
    else if (typeof this.disableddays != "function") console.error("disableddays is not of type function");
    else if (typeof this.format != "function") console.error("format is not of type function");

    const d = new Date();
    let date = d;
    while (!this.disableddays(date)) {
        date = this.firstdate && this.lastdate ? (
            d.getTime() >= this.firstdate.getTime() && d.getTime() <= this.lastdate.getTime() ? d : this.firstdate
        ) : this.firstdate ? (
            d.getTime() >= this.firstdate.getTime() ? d : this.firstdate
        ) : this.lastdate ? (
            d.getTime() <= this.lastdate.getTime() ? d : this.lastdate
        ) : d;
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + DAY);
    }
    this.date = this.date || date;
    this.host.value = this.format(this.date);
}

getDate() {
    return this.date;
}

setDate(date) {
    if (date < this.firstdate || date > this.lastdate) return;
    if (!this.disableddays(date)) {
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + DAY);
        this.setDate(date);
        return;
    }
    this.date = date;
    this.host.value = this.format(date);
    if(typeof this.host.onchange == "function") this.host.onchange();
}
```

}

I've tried changing a couple of lines where the month seems to be created but that doesn't work. Could you point out where the month value is created and how to make it a two digit (for instance february will be 02 instead of 2?)

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please. Your code is huge. A snippet formatting would be appreciated also.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your own arrays of months and weekdays is so last year.

To format days, you can (and possibly should) use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` function, part of the JavaScript `Intl` (Internationalisation) library.

This library allows you to show double digit months.

Here's an example:

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
              'en-US', { day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit" }
            ).format(new Date(myDate))
```

The `Intl` library is supported in all current browsers.

Here is the MDN documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat